# nodemon is not watching directory in webpack-typescript-node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, nodemon

these are the scripts in package.json of typescript-webpack-node.js project:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev:start": "nodemon --watch src  --exec \"node -r dotenv/config --trace-deprecation  dist/bundle.js \" ",
    "dev": "npm-run-all build dev:start",
    "start": "node  dist/bundle.js",
    "tsc:build": "tsc -w",
    "tsc:start": "nodemon --watch src  --exec \"node -r dotenv/config   build/index.js \""
  },
```

if I add:

```
    watch: true,
```

to webpack.config.json then server is not starting. I am getting this error on client side:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
      "clean": "rimraf build",
      "prestart": "npm run clean",
      "start": "webpack --config webpack.client.config.js",
      "poststart": "webpack --watch --config webpack.server.config.js",
}
```

If I run 'start' script it launches next script sequence: clean -> start -> poststart. And there is part of 'webpack.server.config.js':

```
var WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

...
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildEnd: ['nodemon build/server.js --watch build']}));
}
...
```

"onBuildEnd" event fires only once after first build, rebuilds are not trigger "onBuildEnd", so nodemon works as intended